# SQL Server INNER JOIN with nulls value and intersect

Tags: sql-server, join, isnull, intersect

I have a problem. I have two tables with the same columns. I want to create a third table which will be have id's rows from these two tables where four chosen columns will be the same.

I resolved problem with comparing data null with isnull.

I wrote something like this:

```
WITH cteCandidates (City, Street, HouseNumber, PostCode)
  AS
  (
    SELECT City, Street, HouseNumber, PostCode
    FROM Gymnasium
    INTERSECT
    SELECT City, Street, HouseNumber, PostCode
    FROM PrimarySchool
  ) 
  select e.Id as 'Gymnasium',
  p.Id as 'PrimarySchool'
FROM
  Gymnasium AS e
Inner join cteCandidates AS c
    on isnull(e.City       ,'999999') = isnull(c.City       ,'999999')
   AND isnull(e.Street     ,'999999') = isnull(c.Street     ,'999999')
   AND isnull(e.HouseNumber,'999999') = isnull(c.HouseNumber,'999999')
   AND isnull(e.PostCode   ,'999999') = isnull(c.PostCode   ,'999999')
inner join PrimarySchool as p 
    on isnull(e.City       ,'999999') = isnull(p.City       ,'999999')
   AND isnull(e.Street     ,'999999') = isnull(p.Street     ,'999999')
   AND isnull(e.HouseNumber,'999999') = isnull(p.HouseNumber,'999999')
   AND isnull(e.PostCode   ,'999999') = isnull(p.PostCode   ,'999999')
order by PrimarySchool
```

Everything works fine except that code:

```
 SELECT City, Street, HouseNumber, PostCode
    FROM Gymnasium
    INTERSECT
    SELECT City, Street, HouseNumber, PostCode
    FROM PrimarySchool
```

returned different number of rows that the first code.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only be explained by duplicates of (City, Street, HouseNumber, PostCode) columns. Intersect will return exactly `one` row for all duplicated data, but inner join will create `n*m` matching rows. Could you please verify that these four columns are unique in both Gymnasium and PrimarySchool?

Comment: You was right. I have duplicate rows in these tables. Thx for answer!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you are doing wrong is expecting the two queries to return the same number of rows.

In the first, you are replacing nulls with '999999', then comparing the resulting value.  That makes all nulls equal to all other nulls (and the value '999999', though presumably that value doesn't occur).

In the second query, you are doing in intersection without replacing the nulls.  NULL never equals any other value (including other NULLs), so it will return fewer rows.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not reading this right, but I think that this is not true. Quote from MSDN: [When you compare rows for determining distinct values, two NULL values are considered equal.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx). Quick test shows that a row will be returned: `select 'a', null
intersect 
select 'a', null`